# How to determine whether XPath targets (returns) attribute or element?

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

In Java, how do you properly determine if XPath selector targets attribute or element?

To explain the issue: I need to get text from WebDriver's WebElement. Either innerText of the element or it's attribute depending on the XPath. Unfortunately each extraction is done differently (see below) so I have to determine first what the intended target is, element or attribute:

```
String getStringValue(String selector, WebElement context) {
  if(targetsAttribute(selector) {
    WebElement node = context.findElement(new By.xpath(elemPart(selector)));
    return node.getAttribute(attrName(selector));
  } else {
    return context.findElement(new By.xpath(selector)).getText();
  }
};
```

I'm looking for implementation of `targetsAttribute`, `elemPart` and `attrName` methods. Currently I use regex's:

```
 Pattern ATTR_PAT = Pattern.compile("^.*/@([^/]+)$");
 Pattern ELEM_PAT = Pattern.compile("^(.*)/@[^/]+$");
```

But I find this approach ugly and non-systematic. It doesn't match `attribute::` for example. Is there some way to do this using some standard library or so?

NOTE: I'm actually trying to solve similar problem as in following question, only going a bit higher:

[How to get the value of an attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394828/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-xpath)

Comment: A point of terminology: in XML and XPath, both *elements* and attributes are *nodes* in the document tree. So rather than "attribute or node", what you're asking is "attribute or element". Hence the identifiers WebElement, findElement, etc. Good question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of a node-agnostic means to address text content is a problem in many (if not all!) XPath APIs.  And, as already indicated, there is no completely general way to determine in advance whether an XPath expression selects attributes or elements, as it could select both, with a disjunctive combination.

If you can rule out disjunctions (or treat each piece separately) then, heuristically, it all depends on what follows the final slash in the expression: if the remainder starts with '@' (or 'attribute::'), you're selecting an attribute; otherwise, an element.  This is not bullet-proof, but from experience I've found that this is good enough in practice. Your heuristic approach is as good as any.

Comment: Can you give examples illustrating the first sentence? In XSLT, for example, there is no problem getting the text value of a node without regard to whether it's an attribute or an element. There's not a problem in Javascript XPath either, since you can inspect the nodeType of the XPathResult node (it's a DOM node) and extract its value accordingly.

Comment: I wasn't including XSLT, which has <value-of select="string(.)"/> ... I meant a common or generic node.text_content() method, where you don't have to inspect the type of the node to perform an appropriate operation - the method does the Right Thing internally - and which also may fail-soft to the empty string for node types that don't have text content.  That you have to treat elements and attributes differently -i.e. "accordingly" - is precisely the limitation here.

Comment: On further consideration, I think you may be objecting to my use of the phrase "problem" - and I concede the point.  I should have used something like "unfortunate" or "inconvenient", as, strictly speaking, this isn't really a _problem_.  Sorry about that!

Comment: No, I agree with you that where this limitation occurs, as in WebDriver, it *is* a problem. Especially because, in WebDriver, there is (apparently) not even a reliable way to treat elements and attributes "accordingly", because you can't be sure which kind of node you're dealing with. I would say in Javascript it's merely inconvenient, because at least you can find out which type of node it is before trying to extract it; and that detail could be encapsulated in a function. What I was questioning in your answer was the idea that *many (if not all)* XPath APIs share the limitation that WD has.

Comment: But I guess you meant that many if not all XPath APIs have the inconvenience that Javascript DOM does: you have to check the node type of the result in order to know how to extract the string value. And I don't disagree with that (I don't really know; hence my original question to you).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the [XPath expression parser](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.3/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/expr/ExpressionParser.html) that's part of Saxon XSLT/XQuery processor.

ExpressionParser's [parseExpression](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.3/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/expr/ExpressionParser.html#parseExpression())() method should be able to give you the information you need.

If you do figure it out, please post your code (as an answer) because I don't know that anybody else has posted a solution.

## Edit:

Actually, it's impossible to construct an algorithm that will correctly answer, for every XPath expression, whether it will select an element or an attribute. This is because the type of result returned by an XPath expression can depend on the input. E.g. the XPath expression

```
//foo | //bar/@baz
```

could return elements, attributes, both, or neither, depending on what elements and attributes exist in the document.

However, using the parsing tools mentioned above would probably give you your best chance at figuring out, for a subset of XPath expressions, whether they can return an attribute or not.

It seems to me that the inability to get the string value of an XPath expression, regardless of whether it selects an element or an attribute, is a serious shortcoming in the WebDriver API. Unless it provides that ability in some other way that I'm not aware of.