# Getting Attribute using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have been looking for an XPath code to get the value of the attribute of an HTML element as part of my regression testing. Can anyone please help

the attribute value is dynamic changes for every next webelement

below is the HTML code

```
<figcaption id="recentVideosvideoname0" data-videono="xZA6FJ32Twe2GQYEuBHJnQ==" title="test for test" class="caption">test for test</figcaption>
```

i want attribute : `data-videono`

I have tried something like this

```
By.xpath(("//div[contains(@id,'recentVideos')]/div/a/figure/figcaption"));
```

Comment: please search the forum and on google before posting question. searching how to get attribute using selenium will give you tons of information.

Comment: hi Gaurang : I searched didn't get the answer :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value of an attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394828/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the approach mentioned below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'recentVideos')]/div/a/figure/figcaption")).getAttribute("data-videono");
```

Comment: Please check whether the XPath you have used is correct or now? Can you paste the HTML in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To retrieve the attribute `data-videono` you can consider to use the following line of code:

```
String my_attribute = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//figcaption[starts-with(@id, 'recentVideos') and @title='test for test']").getAttribute("data-videono");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get attribute value by using XPath itself.

> XPath 1.0

```
"//div[contains(@id,'recentVideos')]/div/a/figure/figcaption/@data-videono"
```

Notice the `@data-videono` at the end of string, which will return attribute value (p.s. it seems like it is base64 encoded data)

Comment: hey Borna, Thanks a lot it worked. one more question how should i print the @data-videono value. I am trying something like below for(WebElement ele : list)
  {
   System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("data-videono"));
   
  }  but nothing gets printed on console Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question, but do you already tried:

String var = driver.frindElemnt(By.xpath("**put your xpath in here**")).getAttribute("data-videono");